# Change specific parts in Text to bold?

Tags: text-object

I have a huge chunk of text and certain words need to be bold or italic, I finally found out how to select specific words with shift and arrow keys but I cannot make them bold, somehow, anyone an idea? (Blender 3.1)

Edit: toggling bold and italic before typing does kinda work, even though it's still very cumbersome but it doesn't seem to work with copy pasting text. :/

Comment: [This](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/texts/properties.html#font) is the section on the text object in the Blender manual. It looks as if you need to have both normal and bold fonts loaded before you can set a section of text to bold. The manual says: "Bold    Toggled with the Bold button before typing. Text can also be set to bold by selecting it then using the Bold entry in the Text menu of the 3D Viewport."